# need Selenium java code to modify the file name in the download window

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My selenium java code using google chrome driver automatically downloaded the usage.csv file from the site.

I want to write a code such that the file name is saved as "Domain.csv" in my local.

please advice

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the filename using selenium. But However, you can download the file, find the latest file in the downloaded folder, and rename as you want using the [Shutil](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#module-shutil)

**Method available:**

```
shutil.move(src, dst)
```

**Usage:**

Recursively move a file or directory (src) to another location (dst).

If the destination is an existing directory, then src is moved inside that directory. If the destination already exists but is not a directory, it may be overwritten depending on os.rename() semantics.

If the destination is on the current filesystem, then os.rename() is used. Otherwise, src is copied (using shutil.copy2()) to dst and then removed.

Example code:
import os
import shutil

```
filepath = 'Your Download Directory path'
filename = max([filepath +"\"+ f for f in os.listdir(filepath)], key=os.path.getctime)
shutil.move(os.path.join(DirectoryPath, ExistingFileName), CustomFileName)
```

Source [Shutil](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#module-shutil)

According to your input below code can be modified to :

```
filepath = 'C:\Users\Jen\Downloads'
filename = max([filepath +"\"+ f for f in os.listdir(filepath)], key=os.path.getctime)
shutil.move(os.path.join('C:\Users\Jen\Desktop\Fold\QC Report March 2018', filename), 'QC Report March.csv')
```

Comment: This almost solves my issue. I want to rename and move it to another folder. will the above code help?

Comment: The file now downloads at "C:\Users\Jen\Downloads" with file name "usage.csv" . I want to rename this to "QC Report March.csv" and move to file path "C:\Users\Jen\Desktop\Fold\QC Report March 2018" .... could you please put this in your above code lines and explain @Subash J

Comment: How to create local variable filepath?

Comment: filepath = 'C:\Users\Jen\Downloads'    and use shutil.move(os.path.join('C:\Users\Jen\Desktop\Fold\QC Report March 2018', filename), 'QC Report March.csv')

Comment: shutil is pyton related...am coding in java...how do i modify